# A piece of HTML that moves with you throughout your whole webpage?

Tags: html, menubar

Hi I am writing html and css for a website project that I am doing in school and I have made a menu bar and I would like this menu bar to move along with me even when I scroll down. How do I go about doing this. 
My code is as follows:

`<table>
     <tr>
           <td>Breaking News</td>
           <td>Rumors</td>
           <td>Popular Applications</td>
           <td>About</td>
     </tr>
</table>`

I would like this menu bar to move along with me throughout the rest of the page.

Comment: Keep your menu bar `position:fixed` or you may check [this article](http://heera.it/jquery-sticky-menu-plugin) too (JavaScript/jQuery), another idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, perhaps you'd want the behaviour caused by the `position:fixed` CSS attribute. (You would apply this to elements you want "fixed" to a specific position in your browser viewport.)

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TfLvr/) so you can see how a "fixed" version of your table would look, when scrolling down a long page of content.

I hope this was what you were looking for. If not, let me know and I'll be happy to help you further. Good luck with your project!